# Problema Con Función En Javascript

Tags: javascript

Problema: el código no realiza lo que yo quiero. El evento se agrega intercalado en los elementos de la lista, uno sí y uno no. Pero si agrego un elemento más, se invierte el intercalado de los elementos que sí funcionan.

¿Cómo es eso posible si no tengo una función que haga eso?

```
for (var k = 0; k <= List.children.length - 1; k++) {

    List.children[k].addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (this.className === "ViewDelett0element") {
            this.setAttribute("class", "");
        } else {
            this.setAttribute("class", "ViewDelett0element");
        }
    });



    List.children[k].addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (Borradr.className === "Borradryes" && this.className === "ViewDelett0element") {
            Borradr.className = "Borradr"
        } else if (Borradr.className === "Borradr" && this.className === "") {
            Borradr.className = "Borradryes"

        } else if (Borradr.className === "Borradryes" && this.className === "") {
            Borradr.className = "Borradryes"

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Esta pregunta tiene graves deficiencias: ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer?¿qué es lo que falla?¿Recibes algún error? **Añade un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) a la pregunta**

Answer (score 1):

la verdad es que no se muy bien que puede estar pasando pero te aconsejaría que dado que el evento es el mismo en los dos casos (click), agrupes todas las condiciones en un solo listener.

Por hacer el código un poco más legible y manejable puedes sacar las diferentes condiciones a funciones que se encarguen de hacer la comprobación necesaria en cada caso.

```
const checkClass = (element, classname) => {
  return element.className === classname
}

for (let k = 0; k <= List.children.length -1; k++) {
  List.children[k].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (checkClass(this, 'ViewDelett0element')) {
      this.setAttribute('class', '')
    } else {
      this.setAttribute('class', 'ViewDelett0element')
    }

    // Las demás comprobaciones aqui..
  })
}
```

Saludos y suerte!

Comment: gracias probare hacer esto